# Call curl between two project in one server Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, tds

I have 2 Laravel projects on same environment run with xampp (window). Project A is API use database name X(Mysql) Project B call API use database name Y(Sql server).
When I call API of project A by project B. I had a problem !.
[EROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq5WF.png)

It's deteact in the same src. But it's in two project .
I used curl enableDebug
[logfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NHd4.png)
Please help me !. Thank you very much !

Comment: Please be sure to add any error code to your question instead of using images where possible.

Comment: I use curl debug received that.
*   Trying 
* Connected to 
> GET  HTTP/1.1
Host: 
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: Keep-Alive

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2020 05:09:55 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2r PHP/7.3.18
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.18
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
< X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Closing connection 0

Comment: and this is error when i used dd()

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Protocol error in TDS stream (SQL: select [name], [id] from [npo_contract_template]) in file C:\xampp\htdocs\uchi\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 664\n

Comment: the code I used. this url is other project in my server (xampp)
    $response = Curl::to($url)
//            ->asjson()
            ->withContentType('application/json')
            ->enableDebug(public_path('logFile.txt'))
            ->get();

Comment: Methink `Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse` is the key here. It is an error coming from the curl package. Because you are running both url's on the same webserver, your are basically asking curl to communicate with itself. If your other url would run on a different webserver (docker, virualbox, ...) this problem should disappear.

Comment: yup. if i run api on other webserver it don't have any problem but I try to find solution to run both of them in the same webserver.